# How can I constantly change the message being sent from the server to the client?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm working on a little messaging application for me and my friends but my client only receives one object, it's a little hard to explain here...

server:

```py
#server
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 5034))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    clt,adr=s.accept()
    clt.send(bytes("hello", "utf-8"))
```

client:

```py
#client
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.56.1", 5034))
msg=s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode())
```

now how can I make it so that I can constantly change what message is being sent?

Comment: Well, if you want to send multiple messages to the client, then you need to make your `while` loop more complicated.  You can send as much as you want, but when you go around and call `accept` again, the first socket will be closed.  You would also need to loop the `s.recv` call in the client in order to receive multiple messages.

Comment: https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/make-a-chat-room-application-in-python

Comment: @TimRoberts What exactly do you mean by 'complicated'? Could you maybe send an edited version of my code?

Comment: When you call `clt.send(bytes("hello", "utf-8"))` it sends hello. If you want it to send something else then you have to write the thing you want it to send instead of "hello", for example some variable or function call. Do you know basic Python programming?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.  This server listens to your socket, and spawns off a thread to handle each new connection.  That way, it can get back to `accept` to listen for more connections.  The handler then just spews the time once a second.

```
import socket
import threading
import time

def handle(sock):
    while True:
        sock.send( time.ctime().encode('utf-8') )
        time.sleep(1)

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("localhost", 5034))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    clt,adr=s.accept()
    t = threading.Thread( target=handle, args=(clt,), daemon=1 )
    t.start()
```

And this client listens forever for that sweet music:

```
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost", 5034))
while True:
    msg=s.recv(1024)
    print(msg.decode())
```